# Excel formula OR VBA code that could help me with the task

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

- so, I'm pretty new to the VBA programming. I've tried to use ChatGPT to write me either a formula or VBA code that would do the following. **I'm using Excel 2013**

Short description of the setup.

1 workbook, two sheets.
Sheet1 = "Seznam_izdelanih_baterij"
Sheet2 = "Tabela priklopov po mesecih"

Sheet1:
Contains data formatted in a table named "Tabela2"
In Column D ("Tip baterije")are written specific designations of the product. The designations can be repeated throughout the whole column.
In Column S ("Datum priklopa") are written the dates of when the products were plugged into the network. The dates can also be repeated throughout the column, but they are written in sequential order.
The data starts in row 3.

Sheet2:
Contains data that I want to search for in sheet1. The data starts in row 3.
Column B has listed the designations of the products, that are present in column "Tip baterije".
Row 3, from column C onward, contains the month and year that I'm interested in (example: C3 = June 2023, D3 = July 2023, ...)

I want a visual representation of whether a specific product, defined in column B, has been plugged into the network in a specific month. The representation should be done by marking the X in the cell corresponding to both the month&year as well as the product. Example: product 6PFP130 was plugged into the network on 6th June 2023.
6PFP130 is listed in cell B19. The date in C3 is June 2023. The function should fill cell C19 with X.

Any help with the problem would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the VBA code from the ChatGPT. It returns empty cells.

```
Sub AddButton()
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim macroName As String
    
    ' Define the range where you want to place the button
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabela priklopov po mesecih").Range("A1")
    
    ' Assign the macro name
    macroName = "MarkProductPlugs"
    
    ' Create the button
    Set btn = rng.Parent.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
    
    With btn
        .OnAction = macroName ' Assign the macro to the button
        .Caption = "Run Macro" ' Set the button text
        .Name = "btnRunMacro" ' Set the button name (optional)
    End With
End Sub

Sub MarkProductPlugs()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsSearch As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue2 As String
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tblData As Range
    Dim tblColumnS As Range
    Dim tblColumnD As Range
    Dim searchDateColumn As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Seznam_izdelanih_baterij")
    Set wsSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabela priklopov po mesecih")
    
    searchValue2 = wsSearch.Range("B3").Value
    
    Set tbl = wsData.ListObjects("Tabela2")
    Set tblData = tbl.DataBodyRange
    Set tblColumnS = tbl.ListColumns("Datum priklopa").DataBodyRange
    Set tblColumnD = tbl.ListColumns("Tip baterije").DataBodyRange
    
    If Not tblColumnS Is Nothing Then
        Set searchDateColumn = wsSearch.Range("C3").Resize(, wsSearch.Cells(3, wsSearch.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 2)
    Else
        ' Handle the case when tblColumnS is empty or not set
        MsgBox "Error: tblColumnS is empty or not set"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To tblData.Rows.Count
        If tblColumnD.Cells(i).Value = searchValue2 Then
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(tblColumnS.Cells(i).Value, searchDateColumn, 0)) Then
                wsSearch.Cells(i + 2, searchDateColumn.Column).Value = "X"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Macro execution complete."
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet2]

[image: Sheet1]

Comment: "(example: C3 = June 2023, D3 = July 2023, ...)". Was this supposed to go {C3, C4, ...} ? Would you be able to give us a small sample of the data? It seems this can likely be solved through a formula and pivot table.

Comment: im assuming the first pic is sheet 2 correct? are the column values actual dates formatted as 'mmm.yy' or just text values? what is the name of the table in sheet 2?

Comment: y i feel like the question sounds like "how to make the AI write a correct code for me ?" rather than "I had put my effort to code the solution for my needs, but it stuck @ these lines/case . Which i need help with.."   || If u had shown ur troubleshooting effort.. it can fall in category in this page : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .. ok?

Comment: @MarkS. Sure, where can I send it to you? You can see the dates that I'm looking for on the first picture. C3 = June 23, D3 = July 23, E3 = August 23....

Comment: @k1dr0ck Yes, the first pic is sheet 2. The dates are formatted as mmmm.yy, not text value. Sheet 2 does not have a table, only sheet 1.

Comment: @p._phidot_ - I've tried debugging the code with the help of ChatGPT, but to no avail.
Well, in a sense, you are correct.
I did first try to do this with array formula, but it somehow did not work. I also went through a buttload of debugging with the help of ChatGPT. Convos:
No1: https://chat.openai.com/share/d51827a3-de04-4d89-b69e-bced52849d2a
No2: https://chat.openai.com/share/12667078-d118-4f9c-a7fe-4fcb0d0d1d47

You know, I could not be so frank as to where the code came from and just say I tried it myself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer : I only answer this as the tag "excel formula" is applied.

put these is A1:B5 in Sheet1 :

| itemID | date | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 6/13/2023 |  |
| b | 4/14/2023 |  |
| c | 5/1/2023 |  |
| d | 3/24/2023 |  |

In C2, put `=MONTH(B2)` and drag downwards.

(note : all date in column B is excel formatted date, not text. U should get values filled up after the formula applied in column C)

Then in Sheet2 A1:E5, put :

| itemID | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a |  |  |  |  |
| b |  |  |  |  |
| c |  |  |  |  |
| d |  |  |  |  |

in B2, put `=IF(MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)=MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!$C:$C,0),"X","")` , and drag to E5 .

(you'll see B2:C5 wil be filled up accordingly.)

Idea :

use month() to extract month, and match() to get the mathced line if it exist. if it is not, a "" (blank) will be inserted.

Please share if it works/not/understandable. ( :

Comment: Thanks. I would actually prefer excel formula as that would be easier to handle as well as having a normal xlsx file instead of xlsm.

Would this code work with something like this?:
=IF(MATCH($A2, Sheet1!$A:$A,0)=MATCH(MONTH(B$1),MONTH(Sheet1!$C:$C),0),"X","")

I want to avoid adding any additional columns into the Sheet1, as that will additionally clutter everything.

Comment: according to the match() help files/guide : nope.

Comment: OK, I tried your solution and I checked the MATCH() help file and the formula does not give me the result that I want.

So, a bit more clarification - the ItemID can be repeated throughout the whole table, at various dates. Besides that, more than one item can be used in the same month.

If I understood the formula right, this formula works only in the case if in Col(A) as well as Col(B) values do not repeat, right? I need some kind of iteration, that would look through all of the entries within the same month, and find the item defined in ColA.

Comment: Afaik array formulas can do that, but I'm not sure they work normally in excel2013.

Comment: If I understood the formula right, this formula works only in the case if in Col(A) as well as Col(B) values do not repeat, right? <-- nope. wrong understanding.. | this formula works _(will write "X" in the cell)_ only in the case if **the match found** at Col(A) **is located at the same row as the match found** in Col(C). | "In case of duplicates, MATCH returns the first match." --> https://exceljet.net/functions/match-function

Comment: This formula returns an empty cell in my case, where even though ItemID1 is in the same row as Date(6), the first entry of Date(6) is in the row above the ItemID1.

Like I said, I need iteration through all of the rows to find a row, where both conditions are met. Or, should there be none, then the returned value should be an empty cell. I honestly don't see how I can accomplish that without an array formula or VBA.

Comment: I was even thinking of using nested IF or IFS, but that would seriously be a PITB to both write and troubleshoot.

In my head the formula should go something like this: Find B2 in Table1[Date], then compare Table1[ItemID] with Table2[ItemID]. If found, then X, otherwise Row+1 and repeat.

Comment: "This formula returns an empty cell in my case" <-- is the C column in Sheet1 filled up with values after u applied the formula? is  the date in column b @ Sheet1 is 'Date formatted' or not? did u missed any cell? hv a chk @ my sample file >> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O9bvCzKvEWv_8i6IcBIjsnVTRGQjnYi1x8vsrTGiULA/edit?usp=sharing (accompli